# Finding coprime $p,q$ such that $pq=10! $ and $ p<q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, factorial

Find the number of fractions p/q such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p<q$, where $pq=10!$.
My approach:  The obvious first step is to factor $10!$, and this comes out to be 
 $$10!= 2^8\times 3^4\times 5^2\times 7$$ This further tells us that there are a total of $270$ divisors. Now, i don't believe the factors are symmetric in such a sense that, in $\frac 12$ of the cases,$p>q$, and for the remaining half $q>p$ , so the answer *cannot be $135$*.

Since p,q are coprime, they share no common factors, but then the additional constraint,$p<q$ makes the calculations quite cumbersome.

This was part of an 11th grade problem book under "permutations and combinations".

Comment: Are $p,q$ the same as $P,Q$?

Comment: The constraint $p<q$ doesn't cause any problems at all: just count _all_ the co-prime pairs $p,q$, and divide the total by $2$. This works because we know $p$ and $q$ can't be equal, so exactly half of the pairs satisfy $p<q$. (Nevertheless, the answer is not $135$.)

Comment: @lulu yes... for some reason whenever  I wrote P<Q with p and q, for some reason , after writing p<q the output showed only p... this has happened a couple of times before....

Comment: I made the necessary edits.

Comment: @TonyK Your arguement suggests that for any N, if N=pq, then the number of coprime pairs (p,q) are always even

Comment: Do you see how to use the factorization to compute the number of coprime pairs with $p\times q=10!$   ?  Once you see that, you'll see that the number is always even.

Comment: Indeed it does, satan. Unless $N=1$.

Comment: @lulu, i dont quite get it..

Comment: So, think about it.  Try it for a smaller number, like $40=2^3\times 5$.  Same principle at work.

Comment: @lulu, for 2^3*5 its not quite hard i suppose: (1,40),(2^3,5),(5,2^3),(40,1).With larger number of prime factors, with higher powers, how do I generalise?

Comment: Basically, all i have is that p and q do not share any common prime. in their factorisation

Comment: Exactly.  But the higher powers are irrelevant.  sticking with $10!$ we remark that if $2\,|\,p$ then so must $2^8$.

Comment: correct, thats what i just thought

Comment: so it simply boils down to dividing the prime factors into 2 groups?

Comment: If $pq=n$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then $p$ and $q$ are called unitary divisors of $n$. Hence, the question is asking for the number of unitary divisors of $10!$ under $\sqrt{10!}$. In general, the number of unitary divisors of $n$ is $2^{\omega(n)}$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Comment: Yes, you divide all the *distinct* prime factors into $2$ groups.  All the powers of each distinct prime factor must go into either $p$ or $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $10!$ has $4$ distinct prime factors, namely $2$, $3$, $5$, and $7$. Hence, it has $2^4=16$ unitary divisors. Of those $16$ unitary divisors, half of them, or $8$, are under $\sqrt{10!}$.

Answer (score 0):

After insight(s) by Lulu and TonyK,I believe I can answer this now. Say the number N has $r$ *distinct* prime factors. Then the number of pairs $(p,q)$ such that $pq=N$ and $gcd(p,q)=1$, can simply be obtained by dividing the r prime factors into 2 groups. For which there are ${r\choose 0}+{r\choose 1}.....{r\choose r}=2^r$ cases. Which, as TonyK pointed out , is always even except for r=0. Now , for exactly $1/2$ of these cases, p is less than q.